# Byte array to File object without saving to disk

Tags: java, file, byte

I have a method that takes in a `byte[]` that came from `Files.readAllBytes()` in a different part of the code for either *.txt* or *.docx* files. I want to create a new `File` object from the bytes to later read contents from, without saving that file to disk. Is this possible? Or is there a better way to get the contents from the File bytes?

Comment: If you don't want interaction with files, dont use `File`. Pass around the `Byte[]` or create your own class that wraps the data.

Comment: How would I get the content out of the file bytes?

Comment: The bytes **are** the content.

Comment: I get that for text files but what about other file types like .docx and .xlsx?

Comment: A file consists only of bytes. The content are the bytes, no matter the file type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how it works. a `java.io.File` object is a light wrapper: Check out the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/File.java) - it's got a `String` field that contains the path and that is all it has aside from some bookkeeping stuff.

**It is not possible to represent arbitrary data with a java.io.File object**. `j.i.File` objects represent literal files on disk and are not capable of representing anything else.

`Files.readAllBytes` gets you the contents from the bytes, that's.. why the method has that name.

The usual solution is that a method in some library that takes a File is overloaded; there will also be a method that takes a `byte[]`, or, if that isn't around, a method that takes an `InputStream` (you can make an IS from a `byte[]` easily: `new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr)` will do the job).

If the API you are using doesn't contain any such methods, it's a bad API and you should either find something else, or grit your teeth and accept that you're using a bad API, with all the workarounds that this implies, including having to save bytes to disk *just* to satisfy the asinine API.

But look first; I bet there is a `byte[]` and/or `InputStream` variant (or possibly `URL` or `ByteBuffer` or `ByteStream` or a few other more exotic variants).

Comment: I don't know why but I never considered finding a library that can handle bytes instead of File objects so I'll take a look at that. Thanks.